# Nestedlist item's height (Sencha Touch 2.1.0)

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have created a nested list with custom template (I have made custom function `getItemTextTpl`). The problem is that I can't change the nested list item's height (image attached). There was no such problem in Sencha Touch 2.0.0. Is there possibility to change item height?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by my self. They have added new list properties in Sencha Touch v2.1.
One of those properties is `itemHeight`. It's the property which is used for item's height ([more info here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-itemHeight)). To use this property in nestedlist, you have to initialize nestedlist's property `listConfig`. Like this:

```
listConfig: {
  itemHeight: 100
}
```

Maybe you will also need to check new list's property `variableHeights` ([more info here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-variableHeights)).